# Single angular HTTP interceptor across multiple angular dependent projects

Tags: angular

I have a spring boot maven project with multiple other project dependencies which are angular 6 based. I want to include token in the request header for every request that gets initiated from any of my child project.

If I implement HTTP INTERCEPTOR in my parent project(which has angular 6), will the requests that go from child projects hit this interceptor?

If not, can you pls suggest me a way to include token in every request that gets initiated from any of my child project by not changing all child projects?

Comment: **If I implement HTTP INTERCEPTOR in my parent project(which has angular 6), will the requests that go from child projects hit this interceptor?** So you haven't try it, right?

Comment: I did and its not hitting the parent interceptor. But, I am not sure if I am doing it right. Thats why I wanted to know if it's possible or not.